# Rack server with NVidia or ATI GPU

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware, rack, rackmount

For testing our software product we need to generate raster images on a machine with a ATI or NVidia Workstation graphics adapter. Currently we keep a external desktop machine connected to the rack enclosure.

Dell, our main hardware provider, doesn't offer a rack server with the necessary graphics adapter slot (at least for what the salesperson I contacted knew).

Do you know any other brand that manufactures rack servers that fulfill our need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used to be a Dell Engineer, I can remember having several call outs for a Dell Precision Rack that for all purposes was a Server but they still classed it as a Workstation. These had top of the line Nvidia Cards in.

Try looking at some thing like the below option:

[Precision Rack 7000 Series (7910) | Dell UK](http://www.dell.com/uk/business/p/precision-r7910-workstation/pd?oc=cu000pr7910mufws)

Your sales guy does not sound very well informed.

Comment: Its also worth reviewing this if you already have a lot of Dell Server Hardware!

http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/04/campaigns/poweredge-gpu

Answer (score 0):

http://www.penguincomputing.com does offer some server that could be a solution to your need.

Supermicro does also have some servers with GPUs from Nvidia / AMD